# Nvidia driver 290.10 or 173 from additional drivers package?

Tags: nvidia

I use Ubuntu 11.10. If I installed the last driver from the Nvidia website do I still need the additional driver module? I use Nvidia version 290.10 when I look at the Nvidia X-server but when I look at the additional driver module it gives driver 173 in use. I have a GEFORCE 6200. I am confused by this. Should I delete a package?

Answer (score 1):

If you installed the latest drivers from the Nvidia site (290.10) there is no need to install any drivers from the `Additional Drivers` tool.

The 290.10 drivers are quite stable and seem to be working good both with Unity and Gnome-Shell.

If the installation went good I would stick with those until anything new comes out.